# Why are large queues in Lua inefficient to use w/table remove/insert?

Tags: lua, queue, lua-table

From [PiL (1st and 2nd Edition)](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.4.html):

> Although we can implement queues trivially using insert and remove 
>   (from the table library), this implementation can be too slow for
>   large structures. A more efficient implementation uses two indices,
>   one for the first and another for the last element...

Is this because of re-indexing? Or is there another reason why it's inefficient for large structures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer later in the book: http://www.lua.org/pil/19.2.html

> ...removes (and returns) an element from a
>   given position in an array, moving down other elements to close space
>   and decrementing the size of the array.
>
> To insert at the other end of the structure we use table.insert(a, 1,
>   x); to remove from that end we use table.remove(a, 1). The last two
>   operations are not particularly efficient, as they must move elements
>   up and down. However, because the table library implements these
>   functions in C, these loops are not too expensive and this
>   implementation is good enough for small arrays (up to some hundred
>   elements, say).